# Can I use other column in my table as foreign key

Tags: mysql, database

Should it be necessary that the primary key is the one to be used as foreign key in other tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is **No**

`Primary Key` is the `Unique Identifier` as per Application demands. You can use other Identifier(`Columns`) as your `Foreign Key` if need.

> **Note:** But other Identifier(`Columns`) should be `unique`. Because foreign key hold it's parent/related Data.

**EXAMPLE**

In this Table, `ID` is Primary Key (`AUTO_INCREMENT`), `EMAIL` is unique. So, You can use `EMAIL` as Foreign Key in Another Table.

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
|   ID        |     EMAIL    |    OTHER     |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
|    1        | e1@email.com |    ------    |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
|    2        | e2@email.com |    ------    |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
|    3        | e3@email.com |    ------    |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: I have another column in my table that contains unique strings that is generated by php code.

Comment: I added an example in Answer @LemuelDoronio

Comment: Yes, If the `column` is unique, You can use that column as Foreign Key in another table. @LemuelDoronio